# Как работают мультиязычные OCR модели

Tags: python, распознавание-символов

Как работает EasyOcr когда мы используем сразу два языка? дело в том, что мне нужно распознавать инвентарные номера на сканах документов, инв.номера выглядят примерно так "P6ОЖ00, 9OОЖ08, 3QОЖ2383" (первые два символа это или цифра или латинские буквы, вторые две буквы всегда кириллица и далее идут цифры), не могу понять, какую технологию я могу использовать для данной задачи.

Comment: Обычно при мультиязычном распознавании имеется определённый приоритет языков. И символ распознаётся в более приоритетном языке, если он там существует. Вам явно нужна пост-обработка - т.е. после распознавания выполнять замену визуально схожих символов в соответствии с Вашим шаблоном.